# IDA Pro python idaapi

Tags: python, assembly, ida

Hello I have a fast question.

I have been trying to save a full memory dump in IDA Pro in a variable to perform a search with a python script but I did not find the correct function to do it using idaapi.

I want to do something like:

```
import idaapi

dump=get_memory_dump() # Or whatever function to do it

if "foo" in dump:
print "foo is in dump"
```

How can I get the dump? 
Like you can see I want to do a script to found pattherns in the memory while I am debugging a application.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[idaapi.nextthat()](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idaapi-module.html#nextthat)** to search for the byte sequence then use **[dbg_read_memory()](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idaapi-module.html#dbg_read_memory)** to read the memory of the program being debugged. Since the latter appears to make a copy, reading, say, 4GB would be unwise.

Comment: Thank you Scott but I have tried to read memory with dbg_read_memory() and IDA crashed. Does it work for you? Thanks!

Comment: @user1618465, try `dbg_read_memory(cpu.Esp, 4)`. That really shouldn't crash. If reading 4 bytes from ESP works then my guess would be that IDA is only crashing on address ranges that are invalid in the debugee process and you'd have to limit yourself to reading pages marked readable in the process memory map.

Comment: Maybe report a minimal reproducer to Hex Rays